# In Angular2 in custom error handler, how to access error stack trace with line numbers from .ts files

Tags: angular

I try to implement a custom error handler in my app following [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ExceptionHandler-class.html), but don't know how to access the output of original ErrorHandler stack trace. Why I need original? The stack trace printed to console by original ErrorHandler refers to line numbers from typescript .ts files (at least for my app files). The stack trace that is available in a custom ErrorHandler refers to line numbers from javascript .js files.

An example Angular2 app is as follows:

File main.ts

```js
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {App} from './app';
import {ExceptionHandler, provide} from "angular2/core";
class MyExceptionHandler  {
    call(error, stackTrace = null, reason = null) {
        let msg = ExceptionHandler.exceptionToString(error);
        console.log(msg);
        console.log('Message: ' + error.message);
        console.log('Stack trace: ' + stackTrace);
    }
}
bootstrap(App, [provide(ExceptionHandler, {useClass: MyExceptionHandler})]);
//bootstrap(App, []);
```

File app.ts

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `<div><h2>Hello {{name}}</h2></div>`,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    let arr = ['one', 'two'];
    let val = arr[4].id;
  }
}
```

The last statement of App constructor throws an error as intended. My custom error handler prints a few things to console, but the stack traces only contain line numbers from javascript files.

If you comment the bootstrap which uses custom ExceptionHandler and only execute the original bootstrap and check console, there will be a stack trace with line numbers from TypeScript files. Like below (app.ts:18)

```
angular2.dev.js:23501 TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at new App (app.ts:18)
```

I would like to somehow access this output in my custom handler and send it somewhere else instead of printing to console, but with line numbers from .ts files.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {ExceptionHandler, provide} from "angular2/core";

export interface IExceptionHandler {
    call(exception: any, stackTrace?: any, reason?: string): void;
}

export class MyCutomExceptionHandler implements IExceptionHandler {
    call(exception: any, stackTrace: any, reason: string): void {

        alert(exception);
        let msg = ExceptionHandler.exceptionToString(exception);
        console.log("micronyks");
        console.log(msg);
        console.log('Message:---->N ' + exception.message);
        console.log('Stack trace:----->N ' + stackTrace);
    }
}

@Component({
selector: 'my-app', 
  template: `
        main component   
  `,
  directives: [],
})
export class ParentCmp {
    constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    let arr = ['one', 'two'];
    let val = arr[4].id;
  }

}

bootstrap(ParentCmp, [provide(ExceptionHandler, {useClass: MyCutomExceptionHandler})]);
```

Comment: The output printed in console doesn't contain line numbers from typescript files, only from javascript files - it's basically the same output that I got in my original app.

Comment: Its shows relatively corrct output. In console check Messgae ---->N line, in there, at the most right check line number... Doesn't it right?

Comment: Please see [here](http://plnkr.co/vUQDlQyWb4keqtPwaic0?p=preview) a comparison of the two outputs from the app on my computer - the difference is in red color. The first contains the line number from typescript file which caused the error, the second only from javascript.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/QhaOb7GkYsnblXMrBtWI?p=preview look this. it show relatively near line number.

Comment: In your plunker, the error is on line 38 in the editor. If you copy the whole console output to a text file and search for "38", the string is not there. The error is reported as "at new ParentCmp (.... boot.ts!transpiled:44:37)".

Comment: Look at my above comment I said relatively near number not exact number.

Comment: Hi.. I have the same question!  Any luck or insights?